# What logs are important to monitor in splunk for Continuum

Tags: continuum

I am setting up splunk to monitor continuum and its logs, which log files of continuum would be important to monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logs in VersionOne Continuum can be thought of in two categories - service logs and automation logs.

Service logs will give you insights into warnings and errors with the UI, API and other core processes.  Specifically watch for `CRITICAL` and `ERROR` in the messages.

Automation logs are more targeted to the teams use of the value stream orchestration.  Still, it would be useful to monitor the logs in `/pi` and `/te` for `CRITICAL` and `ERROR`, as well as the keyword `failure` in `/pi` and the keyword `Error` in `/te`, as these indicate automation routines that have completed successfully but where their goals have failed.

From time to time, all systems experience problems sending email messages.  Monitoring the `ctm-core` log will reveal to you when the system is unable to send a notification after the max retries.